# Frame adjustment for engine

Tags: frames

[image]

I want to turn my bike into a motorized one, but i can't get engine clearance because the 2 tubes in the picture are so wide on my bike. I was wondering if I cut those tubes and replace them with thinner tubes will the bike still be safe to ride?

Comment: If you want a motorbike, buying a second-hand motorbike is almost certainly going to be cheaper than jury-rigging one from a pushbike and an engine.

Comment: Up-voted because while the OPs _plan_ is not good, the _question_ is good. It is clear, in our scope, and answerable. In other words, it is far better someone asks here than doing something silly.

Answer (score 13):

No.

Those tubes are what stop you hitting the ground - hard. If your modification fails you could have a very bad day, or a very bad (even brief) rest of your life. A competent frame builder could modify a frame if it's steel, but would probably find it easier to purpose-build a frame.

Comment: Frame is most likely aluminum or carbon - steel frames do not benefit significantly being oversized.

Comment: @mattnz I suspected aluminium, which is why the mention of steel is a bit of an afterthought. But a small picture on a phone screen with freehand markup on top doesn't give much away and it's not impossible that someone's using oversize steel gas pipe to build hardtails.

Answer (score 10):

Regardless of whether a modified frame would be structurally safe, modifying the frame wold almost certainly more expensive than just buying a different frame more suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

**NO**

That you have to ask such a question suggests a lack of the engineering skills and experience required to bring such a project to completion, safely.

Also, any engine that won't fit in your bike will likely be too big to be legal on the road of first-world countries.

The existing brakes really won't suit anything larger than a couple hundred watts, which is 1/5 of a horsepower.

If you want an ebike then look for a retrofit kit that puts a hub motor inside your wheel's hub.  If you're fixated on a liquid fuel engine, then try the mechanics SE site.